# Different C++ Redistributable DLL's for VS 2013 and VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I built my application using VS 2013, and delivered two DLLs:

- msvcp120.dll
- msvcr120.dll

Building the same application using VS 2015, instead we need:

- msvcp140.dll
- vcruntime140.dll

Is vcruntime140.dll replacing the former msvcp120.dll?

Comment: You probably have a typo, it is the rough equivalent of msvcr120.dll.  The msvcr library was [split in two](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/), thus the name change.  The second part is ucrtbase.dll, delivered through Windows Update.

Comment: detailed conversation about the topic (MSVC STL Dev included) [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/3fqxj0/visual_c_2015_redist_dlls/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Visual Studio usually breaks binary compatibility with older releases when it gets a major version update. The one notable exception is the transition from VS2015(14.x) to VS2017(15.x), which did *not* break binary compatibility.

For all other releases, when you change the version of Visual Studio, you'll need to change which Runtime Redistributables get installed onto the target computer.

**EDIT:** Per Christopher's observation: Don't manually install the .DLL files onto the target computer. Download the [Redistributable Installer from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145), and ship that with your program, with instructions (or an installer) that installs that first. This link goes to the 2015 version, but you should grab whichever version corresponds to the specific version of visual studio that you are using.

Comment: Reiterate: You should NOT be copying individual dlls yourself. Your target machine should be installing the Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable Package for whatever version of Visual Studio you are using.